# Razor View Errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In my ASP.NET MVC projects from 2 days ago, the Razor views show these kind of errors. But when I debug the project, it runs fine, and the view also is shown.

Has anyone else had issues like this recently? Do you know how to fix this issue?

I have tried updating the Visual Studio also, but the error still shows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of .NET and Visual Studio are you using? I seem to recall seeing this before...trying to remember if having the correct Visual Studio dev packages installed helped or not.

Comment: Can you please show the error messages?

Comment: Is your project based on .net or .net framework? Usually in this case, you can try to add a Razor again to see if there are still similar errors. Finally, you can try cleaning and restructuring the project to see if this issue can be resolved. Because there are no errors when running, it has nothing to do with the code. It should be more caused by Visual Studio itself.